# How to determine MaxLength character with selenium on C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I was wondering if anyone could help me with an issue I am having with Selenium and SpecFlow on C# project. I will like to do an Assertion on several text fields to determine their MaxLength characters. I searched online for help but there is not much coverage of this online. Could anyone please assist?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include your code trials? Please add a [repro].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any C#, but the selenium bindings should allow for `ele.get_attribute('maxlength')` which you can then test against.

I can provide you with the python version of what you would have to do:

```
from selenium import webdriver

wd = webdriver.Firefox()
ele = wd.find_element_by_id(theIdOfTheElement) # Or by xpath/class/name/etc
maxlen = ele.get_attribute('maxlength')
if maxlen != expectedValue:
    print('Oh Shit')
```

Comment: Yes it does, and I can see the maxlength attribute in the html but the problem I am having is I haven't seen it done and I don't know how to start. I was using only Selenium IDE to test, I am learning to write the code myself